# How do I second one's opinion in a conversation after it has already been done?

Tags: correspondence

I am participating in an email thread debating a technical problem with multiple solutions. In a recent message, one of the participants expressed an opinion I agree with.

Another participant responded with

> I would like **to second John**. The following happened to me a while ago, and his solution would solve this case: ...

I would like to express a favourable opinion as well, and looking for the right term.

**Can the expression `to second` (someone) be expressed more than once in an ongoing correspondence?**

Comment: You can *agree* with John *as well*. You can *also second* John.

Comment: You can `third` John :)

Answer (score 3):

You can say you concur

## [concur](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/concur)

> Be of the same opinion; agree.
>
> ‘the authors concurred with the majority’ - OLD

e.g:

I concur with John and *the name of the other paricipant*...